# Buffer a result set with mybatis

Tags: java, sql, buffer, resultset, mybatis

I need to develop a program in java with MyBatis, which reads records from the database and writes them to a file. The query I am using retrieves a large amount of data and there is a risk of `OutOfMemoryExceptions`.

How do I tell MyBatis to process the records without running out of memory?

Comment: How are you currently writing the results?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation I see [here](http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html) (*fetchSize*), it looks like you can tell MyBatis to use a non-default fetch size for its underlying JDBC connections.